# Sequel Pro MySQL Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'sakila'

Tags: mysql, sequelpro

Sequel Pro won't let me run the sakila db. the following error comes up:

Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'sakila'

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a user with the right grants. For more info check the manual:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-user.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html