# AWS RDS - ERROR: Access denied for user 'geornalAdmin'@'%' to database 'mysql' When trying to migrate using sequelize-cli

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I just created an AWS RDS database and I need to create the necessary tables for my project. When I tried doing `sequelize db:migrate` I get `ERROR: Access denied for user 'geornalAdmin'@'%' to database 'mysql'`. I tried the steps shown at https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=227013 and [Sequel Pro MySQL Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'sakila'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36012939/sequel-pro-mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-to-database-s). It didn't work.

Comment: The thread does mention that there are  issues with  punctuation in the password. If this is the case, you must regenerate a password without  punctuation. You also need to reboot your RDS instance if you modified the parameter group.

Comment: @Jamie_D Yes, I tried both.

Comment: @Jamie_D my previous password didn't have any punctuation either.

Comment: Have you successfully  connected to this database via the mysql client (i.e command line)?

Comment: The reason I ask is that "mysql" is usually the default configuration table name and not a database name.

Comment: @Jamie_D Yes I was able to connect to the mysql editor. I can query, but when I tried to do `GRANT ALL ON mysql.* TO 'geornalAdmin'@'%';` I get access denied.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that RDS reserves the root user for itself which is why you have to edit the parameter groups and cannot login with a root password. You need to login with the user you set up when you started the RDS instance, and connect  to the database you named when you set up the instance as well. I would fire up a new RDS instance and choose a unique default database name.

Comment: @Jamie_D Is the database name called DB instance modifier? Because in this case I set the DB instance modifier to `geornal`. But the database name that I could connect is called 'mysql'.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by creating a new database and it worked this time. I don't know what had caused the problem with the first one.